# Kantu UI.Vision - Use date+time as variables for the captureEntirePageScreenshot command file name

Tags: javascript, kantu

I'm attempting to use Kantu UI.Vision to take screen captures of a page URL at regular intervals while passing the current date and time of the capture to the file name (for each screen capture file name like this: `dd-mm-yyyy__HH-mm-ss.png`)

I don't have much experience with JS and i can't get the macro to calculate the current date-time before each capture.

Anyone did it/know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found a solution...

Begin macro with

**Command:** `executeScript_Sandbox`

**Target:** `var d = new Date(); m = d.getDate()+"-"+(d.getMonth()+1)+"-"+ d.getFullYear()+"_"+ d.getHours()+"ː" + d.getMinutes() + "ː" + d.getSeconds(); return m`

**Value:** `timestamp`

Then, when effectuating the screen capture command use the timestamp variable in the filename:

**Command:** `captureEntirePageScreenshot`

**Target:** `Screenshot_${timestamp}.png`